# Is there a PowerShell command that will delete CSV files after importing them?

Tags: powershell, csv

I am looking for a way to delete the CSV files from a folder after they have been imported in to my script.

A little bit of background as to what I am hoping to achieve overall...
I am looking to have our database system export individual .csv files as and when they are processed. These will all be exported to the same folder. My PowerShell script will then run on a schedule, and will pick up any .csv files that are in  specified folder, process these leavers in Active Directory and also remove their Home Directories from the server they are stored on, and then I would like those .csv files that have been processed to be deleted so the script doesn't attempt to process them again.

The code I have so far for importing the .csv files is as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Scripts\Leavers\ -Filter '*.csv' | out-null
Import-CSV -Path (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Scripts\Leavers\' -Filter '*.csv').FullName | out-null
```

This checked the Leavers folder for any .csv file and then imports all the data from these files.

How do I then tell the script to remove these files after importing? Bearing in mind that other .csv files may have been added to that directory in the meantime so I can't just remove all from the folder, it has to be the ones that have been imported.

I am also not sure whether this is placed directly after the import or at the end of the script.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your login on piping to `Out-Null` which discards the output of your command

Comment: You really should have extra code to make sure the file was properly processed, then remove it via the Remove-Item cmdlet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: @abraham-zinala I beleived this just stopped the output being displayed on screen?

Comment: @postanote thank you, I willt take a look over this site.

Comment: Yes, and no. Yes, no output will be displayed. No, it'll discard the entirety of the output meaning there's no purpose in using `Get-ChildItem`, or `Import-Csv` at all. What are you trying to do with the imported csv's?

Comment: Curretntly it imports all .csv files from the path, then it will take that info and look up Active Directory for the home directory paths of the users that are listed in the .csv files. It will then move those home directories to our archive. This does work fine with the Out-Null beign in place.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward. My concerns lie on what you would do after the import of the files but, that's on you to decide. Here's an approach which will import the csv's, do some code, and remove the file afterwards:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Scripts\Leavers\' -Filter '*.csv' |
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        Import-Csv -LiteralPath $_.FullName

        #code here

        Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName        
    }
```

Using `Foreach-Object` gives you more options to process the import by referencing the current objects properties (`$_.FullName` - *file path*). All that's left is to import the file using `Import-Csv`, do some extra code, then use the same `$_.FullName` property to remove the file.

Comment: Would this ignore any new .csv files that are exported to the path in between the import and the removal? Also, would this only remove those .csv files that were that at the time of the import?

Comment: Hmm, not necessarily since the it processes the items as they are found. You can try sorting by *LastWriteTime* in descending order to get the newest ones first and it moves on the the next which could avoid the newer ones given that it's looking for dates.

Comment: I may re-think the process then, I guess looking at a Move-Item in to a "Working Folder" and then deleting the contents of this folder at the end of the script would work, since the script will be on a schedule it will only move items that it finds at the start of the script. Then any that were added during the script running would be processed on the next run?

Comment: Yes, the one's that weren't processed will be done on the next run. That's a bit confusing. Why would it need to move them just to delete them in another folder?

Comment: To make sure it's only the files that have been processed that are deleted, and not ones that are added after the script has been run.

Comment: Why dump to a file at all? Dump the data to a variable in your code, natively form your DB (you can use PowerShell with SQL server - you do not say which DB  you are using, so, this is an assumption), and process the data in the variable, clear the variable data when done, and get more data to process. If SQL server, you can use SSIS with PS to do this without writing to the drive, thus no files to process.

Comment: The DB is from FileMaker and doesn't use SQL . I have this working now with moving the file to another directory, and then cleaning up that directory at the end of the script. Thank you for your help and advice :) you've given my some going points to look at and improve my scripting as I'm currently a novice with this.